# How can i calculate the total price from the user input from select from using php

Tags: php, session, number-formatting, price

I want to calculate the total price of the user inputs which are from $_SESSION.
However, it seems something wrong about my code.

```
 <label>Seats STA:</label>
        <select name="seats[STA]" id="STA">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
        <span class="error">* Please select atleast 1 seat <?php echo $seatErr ;?></span>
```

`$_SESSION['seats']['STA']=$_POST['seats']['STA'];`

```
$sta = 15;
$stp = 5;
$stc = 7.5;
$fca = 30;
$fcp = 20;
$fcc = 15;
$totalamount = "0.0";


$totalamount =  $_SESSION['seats']['STA'] * $sta +
                $_SESSION['seats']['STP'] * $stp +
                $_SESSION['seats']['STC'] * $stc +
                $_SESSION['seats']['FCA'] * $fca +
                $_SESSION['seats']['FCP'] * $fcp +
                $_SESSION['seats']['FCC'] * $fcc;

$tax = 0.1;

$totalprice = $totalamount * (1+$tax);                

number_format($totalprice,2);
```

My questions are,

1. Is `$sta` right way to save the price?
2. If not, where can I save the price of the products from the select form??
3. is `number_format($totalprice,2);` right way to shown 2 decimal??

Thanks for reading my code!!

Comment: Do you have an error ? Are you sure of the values that can take the variables in session ?

Comment: `User Inputs from Session`? Can you explain why you need to store User Input in Session? Should the User Input needed across several page ?

Comment: okay i added full code. Can you guys see any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can save your prices in an array. You can also read this from a JSON file or a database, for example.
2. Prices should never be sent by users.
3. If you want to display the price yes, but if you want to continue calculating the value, `round($total_price, 2)` is the more suitable method.

Code:

```
$_PRICES = array(
    "STA" => 15,
    "STP" => 5,
    "STC" => 7.5,
    "FCA" => 30,
    "FCP" => 20,
    "FCC" => 15
);

$total_price = 0;

foreach ($_SESSION['seats'] as $item => $amount) {
    $price = $_PRICES[$item];
    if ($price != null) {
        $total_price += $amount * $price;
    }
}

$tax = 0.1;

$total_price *= 1+$tax;

echo number_format($total_price,2);
```